# Hosting my html and css files

Tags: html, css, hosting, web-hosting

I'm making a basic non-interactive website.

I've got some pretty basic questions I'd like help with.

Let's say I make all of my html and css files, and I want to see what my website would look like without actually hosting it. How do I do that?

Further, when I want to actually host my files, do I need to do anything special? I read that I can just basically upload them to godaddy over ftp; will godaddy automatically know what to do with the files?

Comment: Just open your HTML in your browser and see how it looks. Then just upload your files through FTP and nothing to do more. Just make sure you are uploading in right directory

Answer (score 2):

a)  You can open the HTML files in your browser directly on your computer.  You should be able to just double-click on them in Explorer(Windows) or Finder(Mac).  If they don't open up in your browser, right-click and choose "Open with.." or "Open in.." and choose your browser.

Make sure you use relative paths rather than static paths when developing.  For example, create a folder on your hard drive called "MyWebsite"  Put your HTML in that folder.  Put your CSS in a folder called 'css' inside your MyWebsite folder.

Then, in your HTML when referring to your CSS, call 'css/mycssfilename.css'   rather than c:\mywebsite\css\mycssfilename.css'  This will let you upload the entire folder structure to a host and have everything "just work."

Typically, you will be assigned a  "web root" folder on the host, and whenever you go to http://www.mywebsite.com,   the web host will automatically display "index.html" in your web root folder.... so make sure you call your opening page index.html.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Will the html be styled if I open it on my own browser?

Also, total noob question but how do I link to other pages in the same folder? Like instead of linking to google.com, link to /page2.html

Comment: Yes, It will be styled.

Comment: To link to page2, simply <a href="page2.html">.....